# Stability of a generalized form of the Mathieu equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am using the [Mathieu equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MathieuDifferentialEquation.html) 
  $$x''(t) + a x(t) + 2 q \cos(2 t) x(t) = 0,$$
as a model of a physical system. The conditions on the parameters $a$ and $q$ for stable solutions to exist are well known and are even implemented as built-in functions in systems such as Mathematica.
Now, I would like to extend my model to the form 
  $$x''(t) + c x^2(t)+ a x(t) + 2 q \cos(2 t) x(t) = 0,$$
and establish the stability criteria for this modified model.
Is this a known model, or can it be transformed to one?
Does it even make sense to talk about stability conditions for this case -- as far as I can see [Floquet's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloquetsTheorem.html) does not apply?

Although the most general form would be most interesting, it would also be interesting to know the stability criteria for the less general case of $a=0$.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure of an answer, but note that your new model is a non-linear ODE. In general (unless there exists a nice algebraic transform that maps it to a linear ODE) the stability analysis for non-linear ODEs depends not only on the coefficients of the equation, but also the initial values prescribed.

As an example, for initial data with $|x|$ very small, your equation is a small perturbation of the Mathieu equation, and one might expect behaviour similar to the Mathieu equation. But for initial data with $|x|$ very large, your equation behaves more like $x''(t) = -cx^2$, then in the case where $x < 0$ and $x' < 0$ initially with large $|x|$, the solution behaves like $(t_0 - t)^{-2}$ and blows up in finite time.

To put it in other words, I am not sure if the notion of stability analysis is even useful. For a linear ODE, the characteristic behaviours are, roughly speaking, limited to exponential decay, exponential blowup, and oscillation (corresponding roughly to the $t\to\infty$ behaviour of $x'' = \pm x$ with increasing or decreasing initial data). For a non-linear ODE, vastly different behaviour can manifest.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I remembered something along these lines -- thus my question about whether it even makes sense to talk about stability in this case. Good point with the asymptotic behavior. For my immediate needs, I expect to get by by numerically finding the basin of attraction for the origin for a specific set of parameters.